# How to change the offset value of ScrollController between widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to change the offset value of a ScrollController that resides in one stateful widget from another stateful widget.

I am not using the Navigator to change screens, but rather simply calling the stateful widget.

In this case, the InspectionForm stateful widget is being called inside of the HomeScreen stateful widget.

**Home Screen Stateful Widget:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

final ScrollController _homeController = ScrollController();

Widget _buildForm() {
    if (_homeController.hasClients) {
      setState(() {
        _homeController.animateTo(
          0.0,
          curve: Curves.easeOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        );
      });
    }

return InspectionForm();

}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body: CustomScrollView(
              controller: _homeController,
              primary: false,
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: _buildForm(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
}
```

**Form Stateful Widget:**

```
class InspectionForm extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _InspectionFormState createState() => _InspectionFormState();
}

class _InspectionFormState extends State<InspectionForm> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return RaisedButton(
onPressed: (){

//Need to change the ScrollView offset when this button is pressed over here.


}

);
}

}
```

I have simplified the above code to make it easier to read, and to simply get my point across of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you already know how Flutter's `ScrollController`s work, and your `InspectionForm` is being instantiated as a child of your `HomeScreen`, so one thing you can do is pass a function from your `HomeScreen` to `InspectionForm` as a parameter. This function would be triggered from `InspectionForm` but it would be defined in `HomeScreen`, from which you can do whatever you want with the `ScrollController`. Something like this (I have not tried this code, it is just a draft for you to get the idea).

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

final ScrollController _homeController = ScrollController();

Widget _buildForm(void Function(double) onFormButtonPressed) {
if (_homeController.hasClients) {
  setState(() {
    _homeController.animateTo(
      0.0,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
  });
}

return InspectionForm(onFormButtonPressed);
}

void _onFormButtonPressed(double scrollOffset) {
  // Whatever you need to do with the ScrollController here...
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body: CustomScrollView(
          controller: _homeController,
          primary: false,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: _buildForm(_onFormButtonPressed),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
}
```

Then, your Form needs to take the function as a parameter.

```
class InspectionForm extends StatefulWidget {
InspectionForm(this.onButtonPressed);

final void Function(double) onButtonPressed;

@override
_InspectionFormState createState() => _InspectionFormState();
}

class _InspectionFormState extends State<InspectionForm> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () { 
    // Compute some scrollOffset here, whatever you need...
    widget.onButtonPressed(scrollOffset); 
   }
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind, but since I am new to Flutter, I thought there has to be a better way to accomplish this! 

Thank you for your help!!